# Uploading File in React/Express

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs, express

I am new to React and Node.js.  But, I am trying to create an component that allows the user to upload a file (from React app) and then have it sent to my Express server (through an API I built), and then have the server save the file locally.  Both the app and server are running on Localhost.  The way I have this setup is that I have a component that handles the Fileupload.  It takes the file and sends it to my Context file.  The Context file then makes an API request.  I am not sure if this is correct though?  I think I am getting the file sent to my Server app, but I get an error that says FormData is not defined.  Also, I am trying to not use external libraries like Axios, as I dont want to have to rely on a third party library for one action.  Here is my code:

**Component:**

```
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react';
import MyContext from '../../context/MyContext';
function FileUploadPage({param}){
     const changeHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();        
        const formData = new FormData();
        const reader = new FileReader();

        if (event.target.files[0]) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
        reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {
            formData.append("file", readerEvent.target.result);               
            //send to Context
            createFileUpload(formData)
        }; 
    }; 
return(
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="file" onChange={changeHandler} />
       </div>
)
}
export default FileUploadPage
```

**Context:**

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
const MyContext = createContext();
export const MyContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
   const { createFileUpload } = useContext(MyContext);
     
   async function FlureeRequest(body, endpoint) {
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    };   
    const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}${endpoint}`, requestOptions);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }
   const createFileUpload = async (file) => {         
     let response = await APIRequest({body:file}, "/catalog/files/upload") 
      console.log(response)             
  }
}
```

**Express Server function**

```
const createFileUpload = ansyncHandler(async (req,res)=>{   
    const {body} = req.body
    const formData = new FormData();  //error FormData is not defined
    formData.append('file', body);   
    console.log(formData.get('file'))   

    res.status(200).json({message:"response.data"})

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FormData` is a browser API, it's available in Node only from v18.

Files need to be sent as `multipart/form-data`and you won't be able to read these off the body as if it was JSON.

To parse `multipart` objects the common approach is to use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).